# Nexus service getting stopped immediately 2

Tags: linux, centos7, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Literally. It appears that there are already many people with similar problems.
[Maybe a question similar to my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348798/nexus-service-getting-stopped-immediately)
But I don't find a solution yet, so I write it in detail.

I installed nexus on the **Centos7** server as described in [tutorial](https://devopscube.com/how-to-install-latest-sonatype-nexus-3-on-linux/). The tutorial records the `execStart` and `execStop` commands in the service file incorrectly. I fixed it anyway. However, running Nexus will terminate immediately.

There were some answers to the previous question.

- The nexus execution account must have path permissions.(resolved)
- Root account should not run the nexus.(resolved)

However, the immediate termination is not resolved.

I think the only hint is the following.
[The official document](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-as-a-service#RunasaService-PIDFile) contains information about the pid file.

> If the service pid file cannot be written the service startup will silently fail, without any logging statements written to the nexus.log.

I cannot find the `nexus.log` file. This means that the pid file cannot be created according to the above information. But it's just `jvm.log` only exists. After connecting to the **nexus** account(created to run Nexus) and manually creating the file in `/tmp` folder, it was possible to create and delete without any permission issues. However, if I manually turn on Nexus in that account, it will also shut down immediately.

How can you fix it? I'm waiting for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered that error logs were piled up in the Nexus installation folder while I was looking at the Nexus related logs. The file name is as follows: `hs_err_pid19999.log`(Only the numbers are different.)

In the log, I found the following message.

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>   Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1890254848 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
> - Decrease number of Java threads
> - Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)

My `Xmx`, `Xms`, and `XX` were `2703m`. And my server had 2GB of RAM. I modified them to `512m`. And now, solve the problem. I hope it will be a problem for people in the same situation.

Comment: FYI your machine (or VM) is way under specced: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/System+Requirements.  Hopefully you're just trialing, but thought this comment is useful for people who arn't that thing those #s are OK.